# Logit Model Interpretation

Tags: r, regression, logistic, interpretation

I understand that R outputs logistic regression coefficients as the log-odds ratio but I have a question about the [UCLA tutorial](http://www.ats.ucla.edu/stat/mult_pkg/faq/general/odds_ratio.htm) that I'm following.

It gives the following output for a logit model using a single dichotomous variable where the outcome variable is being in an honors class:

```
logit(p) = β0 + β1*female

Logistic regression                               Number of obs   =        200
                                                  LR chi2(1)      =       3.10
                                                  Prob > chi2     =     0.0781
Log likelihood = -109.80312                       Pseudo R2       =     0.0139

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
         hon |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
      female |   .5927822   .3414294     1.74   0.083    -.0764072    1.261972
   intercept |  -1.470852   .2689555    -5.47   0.000    -1.997995   -.9437087
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The log-odds of being in an honors class and being female is .5927 meaning that being female increases the chance of being in an honors class.

When they transform this to an odds ratio they use the `exp(.5927822)` which equals `1.809014`.

They say in the tutorial though that `the odds for female are about 81% higher than the odds for males.`

How do they go from 1.809 to 81%?

Comment: $1.809 - 1 = 0.809 \approx \frac{81}{100} = 81\%$

Comment: @Adrian what is the logic behind that?

Comment: All they're saying there is that the number 1.81 is 81% higher than the number 1.

Comment: ok that makes sense. If the number was exp(-.5927822) = 0.5527872, then the chances of being in honors decreases as a femail since the odds < 1. What is the odds were 5.126 or some high number? Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, odds can be greater than 1, such as 5.126.

Comment: Also, for reference on the first point of your question, it may help to review the Taylor Series expansion of e^x (http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=e%5Ex)

Comment: @Jon ok could you tell me what the interpretation would be on a number like 5.126?

Comment: There is a 412.6% increase in the odds that some event will occur vs not. Interpretation kind of depends on the situation. If this were the odds for the female - honors scenario, it'd be something like, there is a 412.6% increase in the odds that a student would be in honors if they are female.

Comment: Here's a useful youtube video on interpretation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xV0AwuDQJ1o

Comment: These comments will be more beneficial as a proper accepted answer. I just don't want to hog the fame ;)